# Very simple sound in iOS

Tags: ios, audio, viewcontroller

I'm trying to add background music to my game, but every example I find is overly complicated.
Any advice or examples that are simple?
I would also like to avoid putting the code for this in view controller.

```
        if (soundcounter > 25) {
        soundcounter = 0;
        assert(@"gmusic.wav");
        SystemSoundID soundID2;
        NSString *soundFile2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                               pathForResource:@"gmusic" ofType:@"wav"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge  CFURLRef)
                                         [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile2], & soundID2);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID2);
    }
    soundcounter+= 1;
    if (sound == true) {
        assert(@"deathsc.mp3");
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                           pathForResource:@"deathsc" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge  CFURLRef)
                                     [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile], & soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

    }
```

This code works half the time, but the other half, it freezes, plays no sound at all, and gives me a SIGKILL error.  (Also the sound seems to stutter at the end)

Comment: Hello!  It would be easier to answer your question if you provided some more details.  Which solutions have you looked at and decided they're too complex?  Do you want the music to play non-stop at the default volume, or do you need volume controls, etc.?  What file format is your music in? etc.

Comment: Basically there are two sound files (probably both WAV).  Throughout the game the first should play and loop.  The second will only play once when the player dies

Comment: Are you developing for Mac or iOS?

Comment: its an IOS game I'm working on

Comment: Are you using any Game Engine such as Cocos2D or SpriteKit ?

Comment: no I'm not.  I tried using AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer and nothing played. When I tried AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID), I kept getting a sigkill error and sound only played half the time

Comment: @JustinBuergi Show some code.